# spellcheck=true is not working in ie9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, spell-checking

I am using AngularJs and HTML to develop a application.for a textarea i have given spellcheck=true;its working fine in chrome,mozilla,ie10 etc ..but its not working on ie9,what is  the permanent solution for it ,We should not make any browser settings,it should be done through coding it self.Can anyone help me with it

```
<textarea spellcheck="true" ng-keyup="checkMaxLen()" ng-model="prvdNote.prvdNoteContent" ng-trim="false" required ng-disabled="isDisabled" 
                ng-class="{showHighlightBack:validationError.isNoteContent}"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The spell check attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions. See this link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_spellcheck
.You can go for JavaScript SpellCheck : http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/